# Is it possible to create a macro that pulls the text in a selected cell, adds it to a file path, then makes cell a hyperlink to the specified file?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm completely new to using VBA in Excel apart from simple recorded macros. I'm currently trying to create a macro to automatically link a cell to a corresponding file based on its contents, for example: a cell contains an order number 'F003910', and the order form is located in 'L:\Docs\Expenditure\Purchase Orders\F0039XX'.

I was hoping to set it up to copy the contents of the cell and create a hyperlink to the file path with the cell's text pasted on the end, which will match the file name.

This is for Excel 365. I've attempted to record the macro and copy and paste as part of that, but it simply saves the text from when the macro was first made rather than pulling from the selected cell.

I realise this might not even be possible, but any advice would be massively appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then improve your question =)

Comment: First of all, this can easily be done with formulas. VBA is not required. Second,  you say `this is for Excel 365`, but what does that mean? Office 365 is a licensing contract you enter with Microsoft. Depending on what subscription you purchase you will be able to use Excel for Desktop and/or Excel Online. VBA will never run in Excel Online. Reading that you use the macro recorder means that you use Excel for desktop. So now you know that the macro recorder records literally,  .... see part 2

Comment: part 2 .... And now you need to learn how to adjust that code to be applied dynamically in your context. There are many sources on the web that deal with that. You have not provided sufficient information to answer your question. 

Step back from your coding dilemma and state what you want to achieve. Code may not be the best answer.

Comment: @teylyn i believe Excel 365 has extra formulas, e.g. `TEXTJOIN` or `CONCAT`
or is that "Excel 2016" ?

Comment: @reportgunner I know that Office 365 has more features than boxed licenses but the question is not clear. Sometimes people think that Office 365 means Excel online only because their company has purchased an O365 license without desktop products. So "we use Office 365" does not tell me at all what product the questioner is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code get the value from Sheet1.range("A1") create the path and import a hyperlink in Sheet1.range("B1"). In both methods dont forget to change file extension.

**VBA Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim cValue As String, path As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        cValue = .Range("A1").Value
        path = "L:\Docs\Expenditure\Purchase Orders\F0039XX\" & cValue & ".xls" '

        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("B1"), Address:=path, TextToDisplay:=path

    End With

End Sub
```

**Excel Formula:**

```
=HYPERLINK("L:\Docs\Expenditure\Purchase Orders\F0039XX\" & A1 & ".xls",A1 & " Location")
```

Comment: why would you use VBA for that if it can be done with a formula?

Comment: Because the OP ask for a VBA code. *I'm currently trying to create a macro*

Comment: @teylyn i have also import an excel formula for  solution too.

Answer (score 3):

If you put e. g. "F003910" in cell B4, then a manually entered formula beneath your cell could look like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("L:\Docs\Expenditure\Purchase Orders\" & LEFT(B4,5) & "XX";"link")
```

And the result looks like this (in German Excel):
[image: Screenshot2]

Example in VBA:

```
Private Sub TestMyHyperlink
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim myCell as Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For each myCell in ws.Range("B4:B100")
        myCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=HYPERLINK(""L:\Docs\Expenditure\Purchase Orders\"" & _
        LEFT(RC[-1],5) & ""XX"", _
        ""link"")"
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: why would you use VBA for that if it can be done with a formula?

Comment: @teylyn Whatever OP needs ... so I mentioned both :)